# remove duplication from react typescript interfaces

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following interfaces:

```
export interface AsyncRouteComponent<Props> extends React.Component<Props, AsyncRouteComponentState> {
  getInitialProps: ({ assets, data, renderPage }: DocumentProps) => any;
  load: () => Promise<React.ReactNode>;
}

export interface AsyncRouteComponentClass<Props> extends AsyncRouteComponent<Props> {
  new (props: Props): AsyncRouteComponent<Props>;
  getInitialProps: ({ assets, data, renderPage }: DocumentProps) => any;
  load: () => Promise<React.ReactNode>;
}

export interface AsyncRouteStateless<Props> extends AsyncRouteComponent<Props> {
  (props: Props): AsyncRouteComponent<Props>;
  getInitialProps: ({ assets, data, renderPage }: DocumentProps) => any;
  load: () => Promise<React.ReactNode>;
}
```

They all have `getInitialProps` and `load` but are different in what they extend.

How can I reduce the duplication in these interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the common methods to a separate interface that is extended by all of your interfaces:

```
interface Common { 
  getInitialProps: ({ assets, data, renderPage }: DocumentProps) => any;
  load: () => Promise<React.ReactNode>;
}

export interface AsyncRouteComponent<Props> extends Common, React.Component<Props, AsyncRouteComponentState> { }

export interface AsyncRouteComponentClass<Props> extends Common, AsyncRouteComponent<Props> {
  new (props: Props): AsyncRouteComponent<Props>;
}

export interface AsyncRouteStateless<Props> extends Common, AsyncRouteComponent<Props> {
  (props: Props): AsyncRouteComponent<Props>;
}
```